# How to prevent outside CSS from overriding web component styles

Tags: css, polymer, web-component

I have a custom Polymer element that I want to style in a certain way and provide as a plugin to many different web sites. I would like to be able to encapsulate my custom components' styles in a way that makes them look the same across all the web sites on which they are embedded. Here is an example of how a font directive from the parent web page is interfering with my component's style:

```html
<style>
* {
  font-size: 18px;
}
</style>
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="polymer-css-test">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        font-size: 12px;
      }
    </style>
    <div>
      Please tell me how to make this 12pt.
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('polymer-css-test', {
      ready: function () {
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
<polymer-css-test></polymer-css-test>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this (and you could even use both).

If you want your style rules to apply here, you need to make them more specific than the "global" rules:

```
:host * {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Also, you can add the `!important` token to a rule to make it override other rules, however this should be used with care:

```
:host {
    font-size: 12px!important;
}
```

For more information on Specificity (which rules apply to which elements), checkout [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: Thanks @timo-d. I'm a little confused because Shadow DOM is supposed to prevent outside CSS from interfering with my components' styles. See this article: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/ Are you familiar with web components?

Comment: It is true that the shadow DOM is somehow its own space in terms of DOM and CSS styles, and it is true that you cannot apply CSS styles to elements in the Shadow DOM **directly** without using `::shadow` or `/deep/`. However, there are some CSS properties like `font-size` that can be inherited from a parent even though the styling rule does not apply to the child element itself. And I think that's what is happening here. I admit that this is rather strange and I cannot find any sources to confirm my theory

Comment: I think you're right. Here is a confirmation of your theory: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/polymer-dev/06zYBZ_IMjc

Comment: CSS inheritance crosses shadow-boundaries. There used to be a flag for `resetStyleInheritance` but it was removed.

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be a real deficit in the web component approach. Seems like there ought to be a way to say, this is the web component style, and parent styles should only apply when they specify something special, like !important-polymer-element or something